# Error Mounting Glusterfs in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: boot, server, mount

I am having difficulty getting my Gluster volume mounted at boot.
It will successfully mount with `mount -a` after boot.

In `/var/log/glusterfs/datafile.log`
I get `failed (Connection refused)`

I have tried all of the solutions [to this question on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/611462/glusterfs-failing-to-mount-at-boot-with-ubuntu-14-04/) to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this exact same problem and what worked for me was using `x-systemd.automount` [mentioned on ServerFault](//serverfault.com/a/823582/269085):

> ... added `noauto,x-systemd.automount` to my `fstab` line:
>
> ```
> gluster1:/volume1 /storage-pool glusterfs defaults,_netdev,noauto,x-systemd.automount 0 0
> ```